# Printing what appears in Working environment

Tags: printing

[image]

I have this notebook appearance in the Working environment, and I'd like it to have the same appearance when it is printed.  Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

@gotwals Look if it is that what you want.

Comment: Nope, I tried all of those options.  Printout doesn't retain any of the stylesheet, it might be something I didn't do correctly in setting up the stylesheet.